# Will disbelievers' deeds be evaluated on the day of judgement?

Tags: jahannam, akhirah, deeds

In my answer to [Do my good deeds committed before converting to Islam count?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36231/do-my-good-deeds-committed-before-converting-to-islam-count/36235#36235) I mentioned that good deeds reduce punishment of disbelievers and I say "it's known that ..." as it is a rule.  I thought this is true as per the story of abu-taleb and he is the less people suffering in jahanam.

Afterwards, I asked my sheikh about some points in my answer, but I didn't think that the point of reducing punishment is totally wrong.  During this conversation, I told him about it, and he told me that this point is wrong and I edited the answer and removed it!  He mentioned that the reduced of punishment of abu-talib was because of the intercession (shafaa) of the prophet (pbuh).

What I know is that disbelievers will never get out of jahanam.  Am I wrong?

My question is:  If the good deeds of disbelievers won't be evaluated if they die before repentance, will they be in the same level in jahanam?  If not, that means good deeds are counted!?

Or good deeds are counted only for Muslims who will stay for a while in jahanam?  And they are the only people for whom "levels" are relevant.

Comment: @Rebecca J. Stones  i meant disbelievers who died without converting i write "day" lol ... anyway in your question i said that the powerful opinion is that converters good deeds may be counted !

Comment: do you understand my question ?

Comment: I think I understand; it's the same question, but without the assumption of converting. (I don't know the answer though.)

Comment: @Rebecca J. Stones my main question is not about good deeds , it's about what is the equation to determinate level of disbelievers in jahanam ? is it good deeds .. or bad deeds biggest or what ?

Answer (score 3):

"Good deeds" without conscious of God is not regarded as "good deeds" in Islam, that's where the confusion lies.

**Source:**

In Islam you are not judged based on actions, rather based on intention.

> **Al-Baqara: Verse 225:** لَا يُؤَاخِذُكُمُ اللَّهُ بِاللَّغْوِ فِي
>   أَيْمَانِكُمْ وَلَٰكِنْ يُؤَاخِذُكُمْ بِمَا كَسَبَتْ قُلُوبُكُمْ ۗ
>   وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ حَلِيمٌ | Allah will not call you to account for
>   thoughtlessness in your oaths, but for the **intention in your hearts**;
>   and He is Oft-forgiving, Most Forbearing.

Good deeds are only good with correct intentions.

> **Al-Ahzab: Verse 5:** ادْعُوهُمْ لِآبَائِهِمْ هُوَ أَقْسَطُ عِنْدَ اللَّهِ ۚ فَإِنْ لَمْ تَعْلَمُوا آبَاءَهُمْ فَإِخْوَانُكُمْ فِي
>   الدِّينِ وَمَوَالِيكُمْ ۚ وَلَيْسَ عَلَيْكُمْ جُنَاحٌ فِيمَا
>   أَخْطَأْتُمْ بِهِ وَلَٰكِنْ مَا تَعَمَّدَتْ قُلُوبُكُمْ ۚ وَكَانَ
>   اللَّهُ غَفُورًا رَحِيمًا | Call them by (the names of) their fathers:
>   that is juster in the sight of Allah. But if ye know not their
>   father's (names, call them) your Brothers in faith, or your maulas.
>   But there is no blame on you if ye make a mistake therein: (what
>   counts is) **the intention of your hearts**: and Allah is Oft-Returning,
>   Most Merciful.

What is the intention of every disbeliever when they do "supposed" good deeds? Is it to please the creator? Is it for the sake of the creator?

To sum it all up, if you do anything without giving credit to the creator, then that deed can never be regarded as good. In every prayer we say "Alhamdulellahe rabil alamine", this means "**all** praise belongs to God". Does a disbeliever ever say this? If not, then how can their actions be regarded as good? They believe "praise belongs to them", that's why they boast about their actions, and show off.

Comment: i know but in jahanam there is levels , satan and monafikin will be in the last one ... so there must be something that determinate the disbelievers levels ... if not disbelievers are in same level  !

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi Yes there clearly is, and it has nothing to do with "good deeds", it has to do with types of disbelief. Please refer to http://sunnahonline.com/library/beliefs-and-methodology/87-types-of-kufr-disbelief

Comment: Could you provide references for your claim in your answer please.

Comment: @Kilise edited for source and explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Surely these verses are talking about that ones deeds are based upon ones intention.  It is not saying that without conscious of God it is not regarded as good deeds. Of course I do not neglect that one should be conscious about God. The Quran clearly states in many places that all souls will have what good it has achieved.

Comment: @Kilise We can agree to disagree at this point, but I will quote myself because you missed it: "if you do anything without giving credit to the creator", source: Quran first chapter, first verse: "Alahamdulellahe Rabil Alameen" -> "All the praises be to God, the Lord of the Worlds". Note how it says "all praises", not "some", but all, therefore anyone who does a deed without praising/giving credit to god is committing a sin.

Comment: Yes, it's Ok to disagree. "therefore anyone who does a deed without praising/giving credit to god is committing a sin." - Doing good deeds and praising God are two different things. Also provide references about who does a good deed without praising God is committing a sin please?

Comment: @Kilise Source (Quran - 1:2)